# \paragraph inexplicably turns into clickable link

Tags: hyperref, paragraphs, links

I have a weird LaTeX problem. When inserting the `\ref{}` link to the `\subparagraph` flagged as "crucial line" in the following MWE, the preceding `\paragraph` headline inexplicably turns into a clickable link in my PDF file which disappears when the `\ref{}` line is removed.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}

\subsubsection{Subsubsection}
Subsubsection text

\paragraph{Paragraph}\label{par:label}
%\ref{subpar:lengths_prems_w1a_s1a}%crucial line: turns Paragraph into a clickable link if uncommented

\subparagraph{ABC}\label{subpar:lengths_prems_w1a_s1a}
Subparagraph text

\end{document}
```

Does any one have an idea what might be the reason for this and how you could get rid of the link?

Best
Thomas

Comment: I don't see the problem. What hyperref version are you using?

Comment: Hello Ulrike, thanks for your answer. My `\hyperref` version is  v6.81g (2010). I use XeTeX under OS X 10.9.2. I have no idea what's going wrong here, but it is a persistent, reproducible problem. `\hyperref` works fine apart from that.

Comment: My oldest hyperref is newer, and my xetex probably too. Try if it works if you add a `\leavevmode` before the `\ref`.

Comment: Dear Ulrike, thanks so much, \leavevmode has done the trick! What a relief – I'd been grappling with this for weeks, and it's kind of unsettling to have something completely inexplicable happen in a 400-page Phd thesis close to completion...

Comment: @UlrikeFischer An answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments: The problem is probably due to an outdated hyperref and xetex. It can be avoided by adding `\leavevmode` (or something else that starts a paragraph) before the `\ref`.