# Hyperref and QR-code turn whole page into clickable hyperlink

Tags: xetex, hyperref, pstricks, qrcode

I followed [this link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/268729/how-can-i-make-a-pstricks-qr-code-into-a-hyperref-clickable-link) to introduce a clickable QR-code in my document. Something like:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{pst-barcode}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\href{https://github.com/alrdebugne}{%
  \begin{pspicture}(25mm,25mm)
    \psbarcode{https://github.com/alrdebugne}{}{qrcode}
  \end{pspicture}}

\end{document}
```

The above snippet links *the whole page* to the url. Regardless of where my mouse hovers, if I click I'll land on the url. This is annoying. How can I confine the hyperlink to the QR-code 'box' only?

P.S.: I tried adding `\leavevmode` before the the `\ref` as suggested [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/209458/paragraph-inexplicably-turns-into-clickable-link) but this didn't work either.

Comment: I don't experience the described problem running your MWE.  In fact the cursor changes as it crosses the boundary.  Try updating your packages.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Did you compile with xelatex?

Comment: That does make a difference.  Now I get no visible boundary to cross.  Alas, I try to avoid pspicture (and XeLaTeX).

Comment: I should add: compiled with `xelatex` version 3.14159265-2.6-0.99996 (according to `\listfiles`), `hyperref` v6.83n on macOS 10.12.6.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With xetex (xdvipdfmx) is rather complicated to put a link around such pictures, as the link area is calculated only from glyphs. As a example

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\href{https://github.com/alrdebugne}{x\rule{1cm}{1cm}x\rule{1cm}{1cm}}

\end{document}
```

gives this linkarea.[image]

pstricks code adds additional complication. Imho it is better to create the qrcode as external pictures (pdf) e.g. with the standalone package and include them with \includegraphics. This normally work fine.

### Edit

Heiko reminded me of `\XeTeXLinkBox`. It works together with qrcode:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

\usepackage{qrcode,hyperref}

\begin{document}
\href{https://github.com/alrdebugne}
  {\XeTeXLinkBox{\qrcode[height=25mm]{https://github.com/alrdebugne}}}

\end{document}
```

^
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the clarification Ulrike. I'll probably revert to just that.

Comment: `hyperref` provides a workaround for XeTeX via `\XeTeXLinkBox` that adds an invisible space glyph to get the correct link box: `\href{https://github.com/alrdebugne}{\XeTeXLinkBox{\rule{1cm}{1cm}}}`. However, this does not work for `\psbarcode`.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek, ah yes I had forgotten. I will edit the answer with a solution with qrcode (if it works ...).

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek This just works exquisitely. Thanks to both!

Answer (score 0):

Run it with `pdflatex`

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{pst-barcode}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}

    \href{https://github.com/alrdebugne}{%
        \begin{pspicture}(25mm,25mm)
        \psbarcode{https://github.com/alrdebugne}{}{qrcode}
        \end{pspicture}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @Herbert. If only! I'm using the `fontspec` package, which doesn't compile under `pdflatex`.

Comment: then simply run ma example with class standalone and without hypperef and you'll get an image which can be included by `\includegraphics`